# Value of keyword this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have a look at the following code:

```
class App extends React.Component {


  go(){
    console.log("Hello",this);
  }
  render() {
    console.log("Hey",this);

    return ( 
      <button onClick={this.go}>Add profile</button>
    );
  } 
}
```

Why the value of `this` inside `go` is undefined? `this` inside `render` is an `App` instance and since we call `this.go` the value of `this` inside method `go` should be equal to the same `App` instance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind `go` or use arrow function:

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  go = () => {
    console.log('Hello', this);
  };
  render() {
    console.log('Hey', this);

    return <button onClick={this.go}>Add profile</button>;
  }
}
```